# Event handler not triggered on specified event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I am implementing an user-input form with complex data-field dependencies. For example, a form that collects user's address: country, state, and street-address.

When the country field is changed, I want to trigger the cleaning process of state  field. When state is changed, I want clean street-address field. They are chained like a dependency tree structure.

Here is my setup in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/innerpeace318/d1yf5uah/10/). It contains 5 input boxes. Their dependency tree is implemented with HTML5 data attributes.

I want to bind a function `cleanSubtree` to each input box's `change` event. So whenever a change is detected, this function will clean all dependent fields. As below:

```
 $('input').on('change',function cleanSubtreeHandlerWrapper(e){
        var inputElem = $(this);
    return function(){
        e.stopPropagation(); 
        cleanSubtree(inputElem);
    };
});
```

However, when I change text of any input box, the bounded function seems not executing. 
But the function will work correctly if I call them directly, e.g. `cleanSubtree($('#i3'));`.

May I know what could the the cause of `cleanSubtree` function not triggered?

(**PS**: I am using jQuery 2.1.4 and Chrome 51.0.2704.103 m)
**EDIT**:  The fix is to change wrapper function. The previous version did not **call** the wrapper function.

```
    $('input').on('change',
              function cleanSubtreeHandlerWrapper(e){ //** seems not triggered
                  e.stopPropagation(); 
                  cleanSubtree($(this));
              });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change :

```
     $('input').on('change',function processNodeHandlerWrapper(e){
        var inputElem = $(this);
    return function(){
        e.stopPropagation(); 
        cleanSubtree(inputElem);
    };
});
```

to :

```
<script>
    $('input').on('change',function processNodeHandlerWrapper(e){
        var inputElem = $(this);
        e.stopPropagation(); 
        cleanSubtree(inputElem);
      })
</script>
```